# Computing gradients w.r.t input / Gaussian Process (RBF Kernel)

Tags: gaussian-process, derivative

my intent is to write down an illustrative example of the derivatives w.r.t input from the

MSE -> GP (with an RBF Kernel) -> Inputs

$\frac{\partial MSE }{\partial x} (GP(x))$

[image]

Could anyone help me or advice me to an existing example?

Thanks a lot!